# Why getting error when installing gulp-sass on app directory?

Tags: gulp, ionic-framework, gulp-sass

I have installed global instance of gulp and worked fine:

```
npm install -g gulp
npm install -g gulp-sass
```

But when I try to install in the app directory

```
npm install gulp-sass
```

I´m getting several errors, starting with

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error    
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading 32-bit node.lib
```

I've tried to uninstall and install GULP again, also rebuild command. Still I got no luck.

Any idea what it would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the version of the dependency in the file *package.json*.

I am using gulp-sass 2.0.4 and the installation went fine.

```
 "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
```